# Error: Cannot find module './candy-machine-cli.ts'

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, solana, nft

I'm following a YouTube video about NFT minting and when I enter this:

> ts-node js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-cli.ts upload ./assets --env
> devnet --keypair ~/.config/solana/devnet-test.json

I get the following error:

> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936   throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module './candy-machine-cli.ts' Require stack:
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
> at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:19)
> at requireResolveNonCached (C:\Users\Victoria\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js:321:16)
> at getProjectSearchDir (C:\Users\Victoria\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js:291:40)
> at main (C:\Users\Victoria\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js:193:27)
> at Object. (C:\Users\Victoria\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js:351:5)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [
> 'C:\Users\Victoria \Desktop\vicc\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\imaginaryUncacheableRequireResolveScript'
> ] }

Then I tried

> ts-node js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v1-cli.ts upload ./assets
> --env devnet --keypair ~/.config/solana/devnet-test.json

And this shows

> [ERR] error: unknown command 'upload'

I really have no idea on how to fix this, would appreciate all the help.

Comment: It seems you renamed the file from `candy-machine-cli.ts` to `candy-machine-v1-cli.ts`, at least your two examples use different files

Comment: When I looks into what’s under src, there appears to be a ‘candy-machine-v1-cli.ts’ and ‘candy-machine-v2-cli.ts’. So I randomly choose one and see if anything will change. And the result is another error shows up.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue as well. The trick here is to implement and get candy-machine working by using **candy-machine-v2-cli.ts.**

**Candy Machine v1 is deprecated** and it is v2 that you should use to create your candy machine.

The steps remain the same and you could try running the below command (which can be found with explanation [here](https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/creating-candy-machine)):-

```
ts-node ~/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload \
    -e devnet \
    -k ~/.config/solana/devnet.json \
    -cp config.json \
    -c example \
    ./assets
```

Besides all this, I would recommend you read the docs on [Candy Machine v2](https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/introduction). It has covered things comprehensively.

Comment: thanks i followed the docs and created a config.json under src and now it's saying "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'config.json'".

Comment: I was also wondering why other people could simply type "candy-machine-cli.ts" in the command without having the problems i'm having, we git clone the whole thing from metaplex so I suppose we should get the same result?

Comment: Hey, so I had the same config.json error as well. I've opened up an issue in their github repo but am still waiting a reply. I do genuinely think that there is some breaking point somewhere. Check the issue at : https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/issues/1553

Comment: My guess as to why other people could simply type in "candy-machine-cli.ts" and have everything work is prolly because they used metaplex's nft candy machine at a time when v1 was only available (and there was no need call things by version numbers). If you happen to look at the /js/packages/cli/src/ directory, it is clear that "candy-machine-cli.ts" is not available there at all anymore.

Comment: Oh yea that makes sense, but both YouTube video I followed are made in 2021 oct and nov, metaplex probably updated the candy machine then

Answer (score 0):

first, create a config.json file in your root folder. follow https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/configuration

then run the command below in your terminal---

ts-node js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload  -e devnet --keypair  -cp config.json -c example ./assets

get your keypair-path by using-- solana config get

this is work for me...

Answer (score 0):

That error happens because you installed candy machine in a different location than this: `js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v1-cli.ts`. I had the same issue. I cloned the project into `~/metaplex` directory in Linux.

```
git clone https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex.git ~/metaplex
```

then inside `~/metaplex` run this command to install metaplex:

```
yarn install --cwd js
```

check the version. `candy-machine-v2-cli.ts` is in `~/metaplex`

```
ts-node ~/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts --version
```

So when I run command to upload, I put the location of `candy-machine-v2-cli.ts`

```
ts-node ~/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload -e devnet -k ~./config/solana/devnet.json -cp config.json ./assets
```

### Note

Since you are on Windows, `~/` this might not work. So write the correct path